# How to find the location of a point in 3D space from projected 2D angle

Tags: trigonometry, vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry, 3d

I have points $A,B,C$ in 3D space and I know the position of $A=(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ and $B=(x_2, y_2, z_2)$. I want to find the location for $C$ given that $AB$ and $BC$ is perpendicular in 3D space but on a 2D plane it's $63.8^{\circ}$

Is it possible to find the location of $C$ with the provided information above?

[image]

[image: Projection of points onto image plane]

Comment: How are points in 3D space projected onto the plane? Is each point projected onto the *nearest* point on the plane? Or is the plane an *image plane* such as in a pinhole camera?

Comment: It's an image plane.

Comment: The angle which you mark as $63.8^\circ$ lies between $AB$ and $BC$. Did you intend to say "$AB$ and $BC$ are perpendicular in 3D space"?

Comment: Yes, it is but in 2d image it's 63.8(or any other $\theta$) degrees.

Comment: But in your question you do not say  "AB and BC are perpendicular in 3D space". Instead, you say "AB and AC are perpendicular in 3D space".

Comment: You're right. I edited the question.

Comment: I have added a diagram to your question which I believe illustrates your question. If you do not agree, then I will remove it.